# draw image from canvas constructor prototype

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to preload a set of images and draw first one from the list on to multiple canvases using canvas constructor.

It seems I can't even start loading images using prototype function. Console log says this.setImages is not a function. I'm just starting with js therefore it might be a very simple mistake.

I left some comments in the code i hope it will make it a bit clear.

There're other ways to achieve what I'm asking but in my case i have to use constructor function.

```
var sources = [
'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg',
'http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_622/u_0/gif/05-kitten-cuteness-1.jpg',
'http://simplycatbreeds.org/images/Kitten.jpg'];

var images = [];


var canvas1 = new canvas('canvas1');
var canvas2 = new canvas('canvas2');

// load images using callback function
setImages(sources, function(images){
    window.alert("Done loading... Start!");
    this.draw();
});

// canvases constructor
function canvas(canvasId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.canvas.style.width = '100%';
    this.canvas.style.height = '100%';

    this.canvasId = canvasId;

    this.setImages();
};

// preloading images
canvas.prototype.setImages = function(sources, callback){
    var cnt = 0;

    function imagesLoaded(){ 
        cnt++;

        if (cnt >= sources.length){
            // passing the objet containing images to load as parameteres 
            callback(images);      
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i<sources.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = sources[i];

        images[i].onload = function(){
            imagesLoaded();
       }
    }
};

canvas.prototype.draw = function() {

    // some code to manipulate image to be added here...

    this.context.drawImage(images[1], 0, 0);
};
```

here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p0nad15m/1/) example

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things I have fixed.

First, I have moved the code that creates the two objects to the end of the JS. The reason is that the prototype functions must be loaded before you try to access them. I recommend using a event listener such as `window.onload` to prevent the code from starting before everything is loaded.

Second, I changed the `setImage` so it is called on the `canvas` objects.

```
var sources = [...];
var images = [];


// load images using callback function

// canvases constructor
function canvas(canvasId) {
   this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
   this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

   this.canvas.style.width = '100%';
   this.canvas.style.height = '100%';

   this.canvasId = canvasId;

   //I removed this since it does not have the right params
   //this.setImages();

};

// preloading images
canvas.prototype.setImages = function(sources, callback){
   var cnt = 0;
   var obj = this;

   function imagesLoaded(){ 
      cnt++;

      if (cnt >= sources.length){
         // passing the objet containing images to load as parameteres 
         callback(images, obj);      
      }
   }

   for (var i=0; i<sources.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].src = sources[i];

      images[i].onload = function(){
         imagesLoaded();
      }
   }
};

canvas.prototype.draw = function() {

   // some code to manipulate image to be added here...
   this.context.drawImage(images[1], 0, 0);
};

var canvas1 = new canvas('canvas1');
canvas1.setImages(sources, function(images){
   window.alert("Done loading... Start!");
   this.draw();
});

var canvas2 = new canvas('canvas2');
canvas2.setImages(sources, function(images, obj){
   window.alert("Done loading... Start!");
   obj.draw();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p0nad15m/35/)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving setImages function inside canvas function like this:

```
function canvas(canvasId)
{
   this.setImages = function(...){ };
   ...
   this.setImages();
}
```

In line 13 you should call setImages on a canvas object: canvas1.setImages();